Autohotkey - Is there a way to replace every string typed?
You can script autohotkey to replace specific strings, right? Hypothetically, is there a way to replace every string with specifically another?
I.e
Hey, I'm writing to you to... -> Quack, Quack quack quack quack quack
additionally, I want to add on a random number service that allows me to randomize each string into pre-selected options, though I think I can handle that on my own once I understand how to replace every string first
I.e
Hey, I'm writing to you to... -> Quack, Snack quack flack flack snack
Looking through the autohotkey documentation, I'm only able to find out ways to replace specific strings and inputs into other inputs. Is there a way to allow every string to be translated into one singular output?

Can you provide some example code? Like, something we can base our answers on? Also, please give the intended solution in more detail.

I think I only half understand the question, so I apologize if my answer doesn't match what you're actually looking for.
Take a look at the RegExReplace() function in the Autohotkey documentation. You can use regular expressions to create very complex search and replace processes.
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/RegExReplace.htm
I can also recommend the following website on the subject of regular expressions:
https://regex101.com/
Here is a code example:
text := "Hello World, I am an example text."

replace_words := {"World": "Earth", "example text": "code example"}
for key, value in replace_words
{
    text := RegExReplace(text, "\b" key "\b", value)
}

MsgBox % text ; Hello Earth, I am a code example


You can quickly and easily create a hotkey for any character that you want to replace. For example:
#Requires AutoHotkey 2.0+

Hk := {toggle: false}
SetCapsLockState('AlwaysOff')
CapsLock & c::OnOff()

OnOff() {
    Hk.toggle := !Hk.toggle
}

#HotIf Hk.toggle

S::Send('H')
M::Send('E')
A::Send('L')
R::Send('L')
T::Send('O')
C::Send('W')
D::Send('R')
E::Send('L')
X::Send('D')

#HotIf

::smart::hello
::codex::world

This code includes a toggle. If you press CapsLock + C it will enable the key replacement (and disable it if you press it again). Then go ahead and type the words "smart codex" and see what you get!
You can also see how hotstrings work. With the toggle turned off try typing "smart codex". The hotstrings at the bottom will replace the words after you press space, tab, punctuation, etc.
